# Странные переменные в PHP

Tags: php

Что в PHP может означать запись ${$variable}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `$variable = 'name';`, то запись `${$variable}` будет считывать значение переменной `$name`.

Comment: Но лучше так стараться не делать, разве что в редких случаях, например свой шаблонизатор написать и т.д.<br>